# What Method I should use to set scheduling priority?

Tags: c, linux, scheduling

I was looking for the old anwser found two solution. I have two process one is batch process and another is real time process. I want to give higher priority to the real-time process.

**One is**

```
setpriority
```

I can set priority of the process b/w -20 to 19. Where -20 is highest and 19 is lowest.

Question are

1. which one is good number for a batch process ?
2. Which one is good number for a realtime process ?

**There is another method**

```
sched_setscheduler
```

using that I can set schduling to SCHED_BATCH mode.

So another question is which function should I use sched_setscheduler or setpriority ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also change the IO priority.

In practice, I'm using the following `reallynice` script

```
#! /bin/sh
exec ionice -n 6 nice -8 $*
```

and I'm doing e.g.

```
batch << END
reallynice make
END
```

The [man page of `sched_setscheduler`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setscheduler) mentions SCHED_FIFO & SCHED_RR for *real-time* processes.

Comment: but code purpose which one method I should use out of sched_setscheduler and setpriority